# Cypress run gives the error "Warning: We failed processing this video." and fails the job

Tags: google-chrome, cypress, ui-automation

I am running Cypress tests in parallel (chrome browser).
And I see the below issue every time when `cypress run` is executed.
I would need to videos for debugging purpose.
Any possible solutions to fix this issue?

```
Warning: We failed to record the video.
12:57:58  
12:57:58  This error will not alter the exit code.
12:57:58  
12:57:58  Error: ffmpeg exited with code 1
12:57:58  
12:57:58      at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/root/.cache/Cypress/9.5.2/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/processor.js:182:22)
12:57:58      at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:394:28)
12:57:58      at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
```

Tried to turn off Video Compression but still the issue occurs.

Comment: The suggestions in this [issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/9128) might help and same time, they have an open [issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/18415) on the same.